# what component joins jumper wires?

Tags: connector, wire

I'm fairly new to electronics.  I often find I need to connect multiple wires together.  For example 8 wires to ground.

What I've been doing is taking a Female Header and soldering all the pins together.  Then I can push the 8 wires into the female header to connect them all together, and a 9th wire to connect the whole header to the ground port.

I keep thinking that surely some other component is already made for connecting jumper wires...  I just don't know what it is called to see if it is worth buying or not.

Comment: Get rid the header and twist them onto one wire. Soldering 9 male headers sounds like a nightmare. Or plug into a tiny breadboard.

Comment: There are distribution blocks for this, but they might be overkill for your application.  You could twist them together as @DKNguyen suggests and solder them if you want something more permanent.  You could also put them into a wire splice terminal and crimp them together if the conductor cross sectional area falls into the acceptable range.

Comment: When you say "jumper wires" do you mean ones with male headers (dupont pins) already attached?